# Wierd async node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm trying to find all musics my users are listening. I'v done it like this :

```
User.find().exec((err, users) => {
    users.forEach((user, index) => {
        Musics.count({ idReader: user._id }, (err, count) => {
            result.push({ mail: user.mail, count: count });
            if (index >= users.length - 1) {
                return res.json(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And it work but not everytimes. Sometimes i'v only 30% of my users sometimes 100%. I think it's because of asynchronous. But i have no idea how to do differently. Thank you !

Comment: Where does `result` come from?

Comment: How big is your Users collection?

Comment: Users collection contains only 3 users. `result` is a var declared on top of `User.find()`. `let result = new Array();`

Comment: Yes, whenever your last count inside your forEach has completed it will return the result, this may or may not be the last count to be actually be completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. In your `forEach` loop you make count query for each user, and while you make the requests in order, they are not necessarily resolved in order. That's why checking for the `index` is not trust worthy. Here is a snippet that should make it:

```
User.find().exec((err, users) => {

    // get an array of promises for each count query
    var promises = users.map(user => 

        Musics.count({ idReader: user._id })
            // format ther result
            .then(count => ({
                mail: user.mail, 
                count: count
            }))
    );

    // after each request to the db is ready
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(result => {
            res.json(result)
        })
        .catch( err => {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).send('Something went wrong')
        })
});
```

Comment: It work perfectly ! Thanks ! I will have to learn more about promises but your example explained me a lot. Ty again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with the promises to get the exact results for that.

```
musicListeners = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await Users.find({})
    try {
      const userPromises = [];
      for (let user in users)
        userPromises.push(Music.count({ idReader: user._id }))

      Promise.all(userPromises).then(res => {
        return res.send(res)

      }, err => {
        return res.status(500).send(err)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).send('Something went wrong')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send('Something went wrong')

  }
}
```

Async/Await would be a good approach to write a good code but needs version of node to LTS one. It would not work with 6. of node.

Comment: My node version is the latest one.

Comment: Using `async / await` is certainly a good idea here.  But you seem to have really over complicated this code.. especially since you are using `async / await`